# When running a complicated line query in entity framework, where does the query run?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

If I run an Entity Framework linq query that has multiple where clauses, groupings and order by statements, does that take up resources on my local machine or does that run on the SQL server?

Comment: If you haven't any materialization methods in you query (expects the materialization of end result) then it will run on your SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "both". You can structure your query in such a way that the bulk of the processing would be on RDBMS side, with filtering, projections, and aggregations done remotely. However, in order to convert the data to objects, the client side would need to do some work, too.

An EF query converts your LINQ expression to SQL through `IQueryable<T>`, and sends it to RDBMS for execution. Naturally, this takes resources on the RDBMS side.

Once RDBMS is done, the results are sent back to the client. At that point the results are converted to the objects that you retrieve through EF, deferring the execution until the point when you need them. If you use `ToList()` or `ToArray()`, the conversion happens right away. If you use additional clauses after `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, or `AsEnumerable()` call, additional processing will happen on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Linq uses local resources, but the translation to SQL that occurs in EF runs on the SQL Server.

There are some other intricacies.  Linq uses lazy evaluation in some cases, so it might not actually hand you the entire collection in memory at once.  Rather, it will hand you a state engine (a `yield return`, essentially; an `IQueryable`), which will produce records as your code demands them.